# Two SELECT query on one table with different ORDER in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table *Table* with three columns: *id, Name* and *Rank*

```
id  Name   Rank
0   A      1
1   B      0
2   C      0
3   D      1
```

*id* is unique index, not important in this case. The table is not sorted by *Name* and *Name* is not unique (this is just simple example).

In pseudocode, I need following (*r*, *n*, *skip* are integer parameters):

```
Temp_A = SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY Rank, Name 
Temp_B = SELECT * FROM Temp_A LIMIT r                          (1)
Temp_C = SELECT * FROM Temp_A OFFSET r ORDER BY Name           (2)
Result = SELECT * FROM (Temp_B + Temp_C) OFFSET skip LIMIT n   (3+4)
```

(Temp_A + Temp_B) means concatenation of the tables

Explanation:

1. Select *r* rows sorted first by *Rank* and then by *Name*,
2. then select rest of the rows sorted by *Name*
3. Join this two parts (number of rows in the joint list is the same as in original table), and finally
4. get *n* rows, starting from row *start* from this joint list

**Example1:** if *r* = 1 and *n* = 4 and *start* = 0 the result should be the same as original table:

```
id  Name   Rank
0   A      1
1   B      0
2   C      0
3   D      1
```

**Example2:** if *r* = 2, *n* = 4 and *start* = 0 the result should be:

```
id  Name   Rank
0   A      1
3   D      1
1   B      0
2   C      0
```

**Example3:** if *r* = 2, *n* = 3 and *start* = 1 the result should be:

```
id  Name   Rank
3   D      1
1   B      0
2   C      0
```

Is it possible to do it with a single MySQL query (version 5.5)?

**Background**

I need to get list of rows sorted by Name, but on the first *r* positions there should be rows with higher priority (Rank). No row should appear twice. Parameters *n* and *skip* are used for pagination (there will be *n* rows on one page).

Thanks for any hint, I am MySQL newbie

Comment: I don't follow your question, but in any case you might want to also tell us which version of MySQL you are using.  MySQL 8 might be helpful here.

Comment: (I must say, in this simple example, it *does* look like the table is sorted by name, and that name is unique)

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen: Sorry, I know, its knotty. I added a pseudocode, that might make it clear. MySQL 5.5

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got it:

```
(SELECT *, 0 as SortKey 
    FROM table 
    ORDER BY Rank, Name LIMIT r
    )
UNION
(SELECT *, 1 as SortKey 
    FROM table
    ORDER BY Rank, Name LIMIT r, 999999
    )
ORDER BY SortKey, Name LIMIT skip, skip+n
```

999999 means "big number" (must be > COUNT table). I have some limits for *Rank* column, hence I can optimize it a little and use some smaller number.